# Android LinkedBlockingQueue take clearing list

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, queue

in my android application I have HashMap of LinkedBlockingQueue:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]>> mBuffer = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]>>(8,0.9f,1);
```

There is separate thread producing data for every key. Data is added this way:

```
public void addFrameCopy(Integer sampleId, short[] frame) {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]> value;

    if (!mBuffer.containsKey(id)) {
        value= new LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]>();
        mBuffer.put(id, value);
    } else {
        value = mBuffer.get(sampleId);
    }

    Log.d("IN "+id,inCounter+" "+getShortArraySum(frame)+"");

    inCounter++;

    value.add(Arrays.copyOf(frame,frame.length));
}
```

And one consumer thread for all keys. Consumption works this way:

```
public List<Pair<ControlFrame, short[]>> getCombinedFramesBatchSkipWhenNeeded
        (List<Pair<Integer, ControlFrame>> controlFrames,
         List<Pair<ControlFrame, short[]>> out) {

    Set<Integer> nonUsedKeys = mBuffer.keySet();

    LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]> list;

    short[] takenDataFrame;
    for (Pair<Integer, ControlFrame> controlPair : controlFrames) {
        if (shouldSatisfyControlFrame(controlPair.second)) {

            list=mBuffer.get(controlPair.first);
            try {
                takenDataFrame = list.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }

            Pair<ControlFrame, short[]> combinedFrame = new Pair<ControlFrame, short[]>(controlPair.second, takenDataFrame);

            Log.d("OUT "+controlPair.first,outCounter+" "+getShortArraySum(takenDataFrame)+"");

            outCounter++;

            out.add(combinedFrame);

            nonUsedKeys.remove(controlPair.first);
        } else {
            attemptToSkipFrames(controlPair);
        }
    }

    for (Integer key : nonUsedKeys) {
        Log.d("OUT "+key,"Skip");
            list=mBuffer.get(key);
        if(!list.isEmpty())
            list.remove(0);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Method attemptToSkipFrames is never called.
I am running tests for one producing thread. Here are logs I am getting:

```
IN  9﹕ 0 0
OUT 9﹕ 0 0
IN  9﹕ 1 26494
OUT 9﹕ 1 26494
IN  9﹕ 2 203342
IN  9﹕ 3 -427941
IN  9﹕ 4 31709
OUT 9﹕ 2 203342
IN  9﹕ 5 457126
OUT 9﹕ 3 457126
```

Looks like take no. 2 is clearing list, causing take no. 3 to get value inserted as no. 5. 
How can I prevent losing items?

**Simplified**

Methods used to insert and take data without hashmap code.

```
public void addFrameCopy(Integer sampleId, short[] frame) {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]> value=getQueue(sampleId);

    Log.d("IN "+id,inCounter+" "+getShortArraySum(frame)+"");

    inCounter++;

    value.add(Arrays.copyOf(frame,frame.length));
}

public List<Pair<ControlFrame, short[]>> getCombinedFramesBatchSkipWhenNeeded
        (List<Pair<Integer, ControlFrame>> controlFrames,
         List<Pair<ControlFrame, short[]>> out) {

    LinkedBlockingQueue<short[]> list;
    short[] takenDataFrame;

    for (Pair<Integer, ControlFrame> controlPair : controlFrames) {
            list=getQueue(controlPair.first);
            try {
                takenDataFrame = list.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }

            Pair<ControlFrame, short[]> combinedFrame = new Pair<ControlFrame, short[]>(controlPair.second, takenDataFrame);

            Log.d("OUT "+controlPair.first,outCounter+" "+getShortArraySum(takenDataFrame)+"");

            outCounter++;

            out.add(combinedFrame);

    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: this looks a little complex, try reducing the code so that it can be reproduced more easily

Comment: I added code with removed hashmap logic, is it clear enough now?

Comment: I tried to look at it, but there is too much code missing. Try to create a single-class version of it (using inner classes as needed) that really runs and demonstrates the problem. To make it fit better, avoid empty lines if possible.

Comment: Found it! I owe You at least a beer Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While playing with simplified single class version of it as suggested/requested by Ralf, I managed to find bug. Turns out issue was caused by manul removal of hashmap keys, not some concurency issues in queue. Fixed it by changing

```
Set<Integer> nonUsedKeys = mBuffer.keySet();
```

to

```
Set<Integer> nonUsedKeys = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(mBuffer.keySet());
```